# How to install thirdparty python wheel library in Snowflake warehouse

Tags: python, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, user-defined-functions

```
select * from information_schema.packages where language = 'python';
```

The above Snow SQL query returns the list of python packages that are available in the Snowflake system (in built).

I have a module written in python which is part of a wheel file. This module does data extraction and loading. I want to install this wheel file into the snowflake system. (by using pip or any method). Once installed I will use this to create a UDF which can later be called from Snow SQL.

Can someone tell me how I can install my wheel file into the snowflake system. Thanks for the help in advance.

I tried the method mentioned in https://medium.com/snowflake/running-pip-packages-in-snowflake-d43581a67439 but I am facing multiple issues as my module has multiple dependencies on several python libraries which are not available by default in snowflake.

So It would be better if I can install the wheel file itself to snowflake system.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot install directly Python packages but there are 2 ways to import  Python packages inside Snowflake:

- using a stage for Python files of the package, as documented [here](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/udf/python/udf-python-packages)
- using /tmp location for Python packages that contain more than just Python files, as the example provided in this [article](https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/Importing-3rd-party-Python-packages-containing-non-Python-files-using-Snowflake-stages-when-creating-Python-UDFs)

Now, currently we only support pure Python packages (for example no C bindings).